# Kotlin coroutines exception handler on main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a coroutine with an exception handler to call an API. I want to update UI if there is any exception but i got bellow error:

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

So is there any way to update UI in exception handler?

Here is my code :

```
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, exception ->

            binding.textview.text = exception.message

        }
        myJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(exceptionHandler) {

            val result = webServices.getTest()

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                binding.textview.text = "$result"
            }
        }
```

Comment: as well as you did in the "normal" launch case you need to switch context to Dispatchers.Main

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi can you tell me how?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no way that ensures `CoroutineExceptionHandler` is called on Main thread. Because you can be on any thread at any time where the crash can happen.

**Documentation**

From [CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/)

> CoroutineExceptionHandler can be invoked from an arbitrary thread.

See also this [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/839)

**Workaround**

You could launch a coroutine on main dispatcher, as [Roman Elizarov mentioned](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/839#issuecomment-439135089), in your CoroutineExceptionHandler:

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { ... /* put code here */ ...  }
```

or if you have a lifecycleScope (because GlobalScope is not recommended):

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { ... /* put code here */ ...  }
```

Comment: Use `lifecycleScope.launch {}` by adding its relevant dependencies instead, `GlobalScope.launch {}` is not recommended.

Comment: @DarShan you are right, I updated my answer.

Comment: What if I don't have access to any lifecycleScope?  I'm developing an SDK and the use of Coroutines needs to be an implementation detail; the SDK callers shouldn't need to know about it.  My CoroutineExceptionHandler calls back to the SDK user's code.  I want to switch back to Dispatchers.Main before calling back.  Should I use `GlobalScope.launch` for this exceptional case?

Comment: Another case where I don't have access to lifecycleScope is in Android instrumented tests.  How should we launch coroutines from Espresso tests?